# Pivot dataset and column names [R]

Tags: r, pivot

I have a dataset that I want to pivot.

[image]

```
dataset <- data.frame(date = c("01/01/2020","02/01/2020", "02/01/2020", "03/01/2020")
              , camp_type = c("acquisition", "acquisition", "newsletter", "acquisition")
              , channel_type = c("email", "direct_mail","email","email")
              , sent = c(100, 200, 50, 250)
              , open = c(30, NA, 14, 148)
              , click = c(14, NA, 1, 100)
)
```

PLEASE NOTE: I have many more camp_types than the ones displayed in this example.

I want to get one row per day, and the rest of the information in different columns such as the picture below (renaming the columns "sent", "open" and "click" based on "channel_type" and "camp_type").

[image]

I have tried something not very elegant, and entirely manual, but I get an error when I rename the variables (code below)

```
dataset %>%
  filter(camp_type == 'Acquisition' & channel_type == 'direct_mail') %>%
  rename (dm_acq_sent = sent
    , dm_acq_open = open
    , dm_acq_click = clicked
  )
```

The problem with this code above is that (once I fix the renaming issue) it will be heavily manual because I have to repeat the same chunk of code several times and needs that someone regularly checks that there are no more combinations of camp_type and channel_type.

Any help / advise will be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyr` you can use `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, id_cols = date, names_from = c(camp_type, channel_type), values_from = c(sent, open, click))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  date       sent_acquisition… sent_acquisition_… sent_newsletter_… open_acquisitio… open_acquisition… open_newsletter… click_acquisiti… click_acquisitio… click_newslette…
  <date>                 <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
1 2020-01-01               100                 NA                NA               30                NA               NA               14                NA               NA
2 2020-02-01                NA                200                50               NA                NA               14               NA                NA                1
3 2020-03-01               250                 NA                NA              148                NA               NA              100                NA               NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18262, 18293, 18293, 18322), class = "Date"), 
    camp_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("acquisition", 
    "newsletter"), class = "factor"), channel_type = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("direct_email", "email"), class = "factor"), 
    sent = c(100, 200, 50, 250), open = c(30, NA, 14, 148), click = c(14, 
    NA, 1, 100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!